# qt Program crush with segmentation fault while switching cental widget

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I tried maybe everything but I just don't see a mistake in this code. I made two windows inherited from QMainWindow: one with qt designer and another just in constructor. I'm trying to switch these windows in the MainWindow class depending on what buttons you press.

1. LoginWindow.cpp

```
LoginWindow::LoginWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::LoginWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

LoginWindow::~LoginWindow() {
    delete ui;
}


void LoginWindow::on_confirmButton_clicked() {
    emit confirmButton_clicked();
}
```

2. RegistrationWindow.hpp

```
RegistrationWindow::RegistrationWindow(QWidget* parent): QMainWindow(parent) {

    label = new QLabel("Fast Typing"); //variable in .hpp
    label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    label->setFont(QFont("Lucida Console", 12, 2));
    QVBoxLayout * l = new QVBoxLayout();
    l->addWidget(label);
    l->addWidget(new QLabel("Login", this));
    l->addWidget(new QLineEdit(this));
    l->addWidget(new QLabel("Password", this));
    l->addWidget(new QLineEdit(this));
    p = new QPushButton("Confirm", this); //variable in .hpp
    l->addWidget(p);
    w = new QWidget(); //variable in .hpp
    w->setLayout(l);
    setCentralWidget(w);

    connect(p, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &RegistrationWindow::on_confirmButton_clicked);
}

void RegistrationWindow::on_confirmButton_clicked() {
    emit confirmButton_clicked();
}

RegistrationWindow::~RegistrationWindow() { }
```

3. MainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    //variables in .hpp
    logWindow = new LoginWindow();
    regWindow = new RegistrationWindow();
    goToReg();

    connect(logWindow, SIGNAL(confirmButton_clicked()), this, SLOT(goToReg()));
    connect(regWindow, SIGNAL(confirmButton_clicked()), this, SLOT(goToLog()));
}

void MainWindow::goToReg() {
    qDebug() << "goToReg";
    resize(regWindow->size());
    qDebug() << "goToReg";
    setCentralWidget(regWindow);
    setWindowTitle("Registration");
    qDebug() << "registration: " << regWindow;
    qDebug() << "login: " << logWindow;
}

void MainWindow::goToLog() {
    qDebug() << "goToLog";
    resize(logWindow->size());
    qDebug() << "goToLog";
    setCentralWidget(logWindow);
    setWindowTitle("Login");
    qDebug() << "registration: " << regWindow;
    qDebug() << "login: " << logWindow;
}
```

All I could say is it switches windows no matter what I make a starting window and for second time it's crashes on the line setCentralWidget() in slot with SEGV runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) of `QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`:

> Note: QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time.

The widgets that `logWindow` and `regWindow` point to start life unowned. Then you call `goToReg()`, which calls `setCentralWidget(regWindow)` - now the main window owns `*regWindow`. Then you call `goToLog()`, which calls `setCentralWidget(logWindow)` - now the main window takes ownership of `*logWindow` and **destroys** `*regWindow`, so `regWindow` becomes a dangling pointer. Next time you attempt to use it, the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Then how I exactly circumvent such behaviour in my code? Do I create these widgets in place? But if construction and deletion is a performance issue, how i prevent qt from deleting pointer? mb shared_ptr will help?

Comment: Call `takeCentralWidget()` before `setCentralWidget()`

Comment: Ok, I'll better go read documentation for a while. Thank you very much.